# selenium c# how to switching silently between tabs google chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to switch between tabs silently without popup of the window of chrome because when I hid chrome and start automation it popup every switching of tab

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _...popup every switching of tab..._

Comment: when the automation starting I want to hide the window of chrome untile the end of automation but the window popup every opening or switching of tabs